# What are the possibilites to embed content from other pages on my own page

Tags: php, javascript, html, embed, embedding

Hello this is may first question and I have found so far the following alternatives:

1. ServerSideInclude
2. embedding complete pages via iframe
3. to parse xml and translate into html

It would be nice, if you have some more suggestions.
Thanks for your patience.

Best regards Matthias Günther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<object>`

I did not know you could use the object tag to embed text/html documents. I was researching this and came upon this W3C paper. I doubt this should be your first choice, but the question asked for the possibilities, not recommendations.

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331

> **IFRAME vs OBJECT**
>   Although a means for creating compound documents is recognized to be a real need the introduction of IFRAME to meet this need is arguable. The main reason is that compound documents can already be created using the existing OBJECT element. Indeed, the purpose of IFRAME is to provide authors with a way to insert HTML documents into an HTML document. At the same time the OBJECT element is designed to provide a general mechanism to insert any type of object into an HTML document. Based on this and given that an HTML document is only a particular type of object, it is reasonable to claim that IFRAME is not necessary, and that OBJECT should be used instead.

Comment: While this is all currently true, you should note that in HTML5, IFRAME will obtain capabilities beyond those of OBJECT. Possibly most useful will be the "seamless" attribute. (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/text-level-semantics.html#attr-iframe-seamless)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use some kind of JavaScript library (e.g. [JQuery](http://jquery.com)) and pull the data into your page via AJAX

Comment: This solution will be subject to the SOP.

Comment: @Colin
what do you mean with SOP?

Comment: Same Origin Policy ]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy]
Might or might not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that the only answer is `1.` PHP or any other sever side language can be used too.
As 2. is not an option at all and 3. does not include any pages.

Can you explain what pages you want to include? The answer may depend on it

Comment: Hello Col,

I want to integrate some image galeries (for example visit the page http://www.pictrs.com/lichtspuren). So I have to specify the content/area of the page I want. Maybe another solution is to communicate with the api to get according responses.

Comment: Hello @Matt . In the server-side programming there is no page including at all. Every page being generated from some data based on some logic. Just generate any page as you wish. What api you're talking about?

Comment: @Col

I had the twitter api in mind which I also used with cURL to get information via json. This was pretty cool, but I have no experience in writting an api.

Comment: @Matt twitter API is cross-site api, while your goal is single site, I assume. Just male 2 scripts, one showing single picture and another showing whole gallery, reading puctureas from disk. that's all

Comment: @Col
and what script do you suggest for this task?

Comment: @Matt if you're talking of ready made scripts I'd suggest Menalto gallery. Thought you asked how to program

Comment: I actually meant to programm :) - sorry for my inaccuracy. I don't want to use some prebuild galleries. I have experience with ruby and bash - so these things must be enough.